# Full height background image with paddings and centered text

Tags: html, css, alignment

How to attach a background image like this with paddings around (only top, left, right)? I have this logo and the main text inside of it but I need to align middle the logo between the top (without padding) and main text. Is this possible?

[image]

```
    <div class="t-row">
      <div class="image-wrapper">
        <div class="canvas-image">
          <div class="logo-container">
            <img src="img/logo2x.png" alt="Logo">
          </div>
          <div class="content">
                TEXT HERE
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="t-row">
      <div class="footer-text">
        <div class="footer-cell">
           TEXT HERE
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


html {
  height:100%;
}
body {
  min-height:100%;
}
.t-row:first-child {
  height: 81.5%;
  padding: 17px 17px 0 17px;
}
.image-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(../img/background-phone.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: What have to tried so far?

Comment: Display table / table-cell -> It doesn't work.

Comment: How you want to align, `horizontally middle` or `vertically middle`?

Comment: Please post your code here. Depending on that we will guide you to right direction.

Comment: `vertically middle`. Unfortunately, I really don't know where to start (again)

Comment: and the css where is ???We can't suppose your classes

Comment: I've added the first draft of html and css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `display:inline-block` and `pseudo` to achieve this,

**[Source](https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/)**

```css
html,body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  background: url('http://www.hutterites.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/placeholder.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  height:100vh;
}
.wrapper:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.childDiv {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.logo, 
.text{
  width:400px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 30px 0;
  background: #fff;
}
.text{
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="childDiv">
    <div class="logo">logo</div>
    <div class="text">text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome idea, but how to add it as `background-image`?

Comment: Didn't get you! for which element you want to use `bg-image` ?

Comment: For that `wrapper`!

Comment: Thank you very much Abhishek! The only thing that still gives me pain in the ass is that the `logo` needs to be vertical aligned between the top and the text....

Comment: You can use `margin-bottom` to create equal space, or you will figure out any other way, after all you're a developer.